# Moving a Rectangle to the position where a mouse click happen

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to create a project where the user clicks on the screen and then a rectangle will move to the position where the clicked occurred. My intention was to get the center of the rectangle to move the exact location of the click but my code only moves the rectangle into the general area of where the click occurred. My question is how do I get the center of the rectangle to move the exact location of where a mouse click occurs?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50,50,50,50);
    rec.setLayoutX(200);
    rec.setLayoutY(200);

    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.50), rec);
    transition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            rec.setLayoutX(rec.getTranslateX() + rec.getLayoutX());
            rec.setLayoutY(rec.getTranslateY() + rec.getLayoutY());
            rec.setTranslateX(0);
            rec.setTranslateY(0);
        }
    });

    scene.setOnMousePressed(e->{
        transition.setToX(e.getSceneX() - rec.getLayoutX());
        transition.setToY(e.getSceneY() - rec.getLayoutY());
        transition.playFromStart();
    });

    root.getChildren().add(rec);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ignore the `x`/`y` properties of the `Rectangle` which also shift the position where the `Rectangle` is drawn. Furthermore for the center to be moved to this position, you need to also subtract half the `width`/`height` from the position to move to...

Also I recommend using a `Pane` instead of `BorderPane`, is you want to set the `layoutX`/`layoutY` properties yourself. Nonetheless in this case it should work too with some small adjustments:

```
scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    transition.setToX(e.getSceneX() - rec.getLayoutX() - rec.getWidth() / 2 - rec.getX());
    transition.setToY(e.getSceneY() - rec.getLayoutY() - rec.getHeight() / 2 - rec.getY());
    transition.playFromStart();
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I am trying to learn about Transitions and stuff similar to it. This was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete sample using a Pane as suggested by fabian.

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Translator extends Application {
    private static final double W = 400, H = 400;
    private static final double S = 50;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(W / 2 - S / 2,H / 2 - S / 2,S,S);

        TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), rec);
        transition.setOnFinished(t -> {
            rec.setX(rec.getTranslateX() + rec.getX());
            rec.setY(rec.getTranslateY() + rec.getY());
            rec.setTranslateX(0);
            rec.setTranslateY(0);
        });

        Pane root = new Pane(rec);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,W,H);

        root.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            transition.stop();
            transition.setToX(e.getX() - S / 2 - rec.getX());
            transition.setToY(e.getY() - S / 2 - rec.getY());
            transition.playFromStart();
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool thank you. I have actually been referencing a project on your GitHub page that you posted in 2013 where you show how to transition a circle by either pressing the arrow keys, clicking the mouse or holding ctrl and clicking the mouse. It has been huge in helping me learn about Transitions and stuff, so thank you I am very thankful you made that.